# Reading xml document in firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, xml-parsing

I am trying to read customers.xml using javascript.

My professor has taught us to read xml using `ActiveXObjectand he has given us an assignment to create a sample login page which checks username and password by reading customers.xml.

I am trying to use `DOMParser` so that it works with firefox.

But when I click on Login button I get this error.

> Error: syntax error Source File:
>   file:///C:/Users/Searock/Desktop/home/project/project/login.html
>   Line: 1, Column: 1 Source Code:
>   customers.xml

Here's my code.

**login.js**

```
var xmlDoc = 0;

function checkUser()
{
    var user = document.login.txtLogin.value;
    var pass = document.login.txtPass.value;
    //xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    /*
    xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
    xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = redirectUser;
    xmlDoc.load("customers.xml");

    */
    var parser = new DOMParser();          
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString("customers.xml", "text/xml");
    alert(xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName);

    xmlDoc.async = "false";
    xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = redirectUser;                
}

function redirectUser()
{
    alert('');
    var user = document.login.txtLogin.value;
    var pass = document.login.txtPass.value;
    var log = 0;
    if(xmlDoc.readyState == 4)
    {
        xmlObj = xmlDoc.documentElement;
        var len = xmlObj.childNodes.length;

        for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            var nodeElement = xmlObj.childNodes[i];
            var userXml = nodeElement.childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var passXml = nodeElement.childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var idXML = nodeElement.attributes[0].value

            if(userXml == user && passXml == pass)
            {
                log = 1;
                document.cookie = escape(idXML);
                document.login.submit();
            }
        }
    }

    if(log == 0)
    {
        var divErr = document.getElementById('Error');
        divErr.innerHTML = "<b>Login Failed</b>";

    }
}
```

**customers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<customers>
    <customer custid="CU101">
        <user>jack</user>
        <pwd>PW101</pwd>
        <email>jack@rediff.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custid="CU102">
        <user>jill</user>
        <pwd>PW102</pwd>
        <email>jill@rediff.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custid="CU103">
        <user>john</user>
        <pwd>PW103</pwd>
        <email>john@rediff.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custid="CU104">
        <user>jeff</user>
        <pwd>PW104</pwd>
        <email>jeff@rediff.com</email>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

I get parsererror message on line `alert(xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName);`

I don't know what's wrong with my code. Can some one point me in a right direction?

**Edit :**

Ok, I found a solution.

```
var xmlDoc = 0;
var xhttp = 0;
function checkUser()
{
    var user = document.login.txtLogin.value;
    var pass = document.login.txtPass.value;
    var err = "";
    if(user == "" || pass == "")
    {
        if(user == "")
        {
            alert("Enter user name");
        }

        if(pass == "")
        {
            alert("Enter Password");
        }

        return;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else // IE 5/6
    {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = redirectUser;        
    xhttp.open("GET","customers.xml",true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function redirectUser()
{
    var log = 2;
    var user = document.login.txtLogin.value;
    var pass = document.login.txtPass.value;
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        log = 0;
        xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
        var xmlUsers = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('user');
        var xmlPasswords = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('pwd');
        var userLen = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('customer').length;
        var xmlCustomers = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('customer');

        for (var i = 0; i <  userLen; i++)
        {
            var xmlUser = xmlUsers[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var xmlPass = xmlPasswords[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var xmlId = xmlCustomers.item(i).attributes[0].nodeValue;

            if(xmlUser == user && xmlPass == pass)
            {
                log = 1;
                document.cookie = xmlId;
                document.login.submit();
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    if(log == 0)
    {
        alert("Login failed");
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseFromString` is parsing the string "customer.xml" in your case, because the first argument needs to be a string containing the actual content of the XML document and not its name.

You can use something like this to get the xml file:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // IE 5/6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET","customer.xml",false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_parser.asp)

Comment: xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML; is working fine. Can you hel me with parsing the document because I get error with my above code.